# Are there alternative UIs for Swagger files

Tags: rest, swagger-ui, postman

We are currently using `Postman` for building and testing our REST endpoints. There are some serious drawbacks in their product when it comes to sharing a collection. Basically you can't use source control for the document because it changes all the guids in json file when you import.

So we're looking at possibly switching to `Swagger`, the issue with Swagger is that `SwaggerUI` isn't very user friendly. We like that Postman gives you the ability to break up your collections into folders, and gives you a split screen where you can run a request and see the output.

Are there any third party tools which give a `Postman` style interface to `Swagger` files? i.e. easy to find a set of methods for a resource, and to make calls to it.

Answer (score 5):

[Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) provides a *live documentation* for your API and you always can *customize* it to meet your needs. It's not that difficult. From the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#customize):

> ### Customize
>
> You may choose to customize Swagger UI for your organization. Here is
>   an overview of what's in its various directories:
>
> - `dist`: Contains a distribution which you can deploy on a server or load
>     from your local machine.
> - `dist/lang`: Swagger localization.
> - `lib`: Contains JavaScript dependencies which Swagger UI depends on.
> - `node_modules`: Node modules which Swagger UI uses for its
>     development.
> - `src/main/templates`: Handlebars templates used to
>     render Swagger UI.
> - `src/main/html`: The HTML files, some images and CSS.
> - `src/main/javascript`: Main code.

For additional details, have a look at the [Swagger UI documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui).

---

### Themes

- Alternatively to the default Swagger UI theme, have a look at this [Swagger UI responsive theme](https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui), inspired in the Auth0 API explorer.
- You also might like [these themes](https://github.com/ostranme/swagger-ui-themes), which are just modifications on the default Swagger UI theme.

### Warning

Please note Swagger is **not** an *API testing tool*. It's an *API documentation tool*.

Answer (score -1):

So you have two requirements for an API user interface:

> 1. easy to find a set of methods for a resource
> 2. make calls to resource methods

It seem SwaggerUI is what you need. See [demo here](http://petstore.swagger.io/).

1. You can click `Expand Operations` and use your browser search function to find a resource or operation by its name.
2. You can submit a request, you will be notified when a required field is blank, check a resource request/response model.

Check, for example, the method `GET /store/order/{orderId}`.

Hit the `Try it out!` button after entering an `orderId` and the request will be submitted from the UI.

Comment: I have seen SwaggerUI, as mentioned in the original post, but we're not happy with the interface. The layout of a single long expandable list is not particularly useful. I'm looking for an alternative layout or UI for Swagger UI, or a completely separate tool. We might go with Swagger/Postman combination.